# OpenCV4Android Sample App - what does this code snippet do?

Tags: android, opencv

What is happening from line #129 to line #133 in [this class](https://github.com/nehiljain/opencv4android/blob/master/samples/color-blob-detection/src/org/opencv/samples/colorblobdetect/ColorBlobDetectionActivity.java) of the Color blob detection sample app?

**SOME CONTEXT:**

The camera view in the app looks like this: *(Notice that in the camera view, there is a black border around the camera frame)*

[image]
([**If you can't see the image, check it here.**](http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/145224507513221.jpg))

From Line 114 to 128, the following is happening.

1. **`int cols = mRgba.cols();`**  `cols()` gives the number of columns in a matrix. The matrix here is the Mat representing a frame in the live stream of frames being displayed (and not the entire camera view), i.e. it represents the part of the camera view where live stream is being displayed, EXCLUDING the black border of the camera view.
2. **`int rows = mRgba.rows();`** `rows()` gives the number of rows in the camera frame, EXCLUDING the black border of the camera view.
3. **`int xOffset = (mOpenCvCameraView.getWidth() - cols) / 2;  int yOffset = (mOpenCvCameraView.getHeight() - rows) / 2;`** `mOpenCvCameraView.getWidth()` gives the number of rows in the entire camera view, i.e. the camera frame PLUS the black border of the camera view around the frame. `(mOpenCvCameraView.getWidth() - cols)` gives the sum of the width of left and right black border of the camera view. `(mOpenCvCameraView.getWidth() - cols)/2` or `xOffset` gives the width of the black border on one side, i.e. either right or left side, black border of the camera view. *Likewise for `yOffset`*
4. **`int x = (int)event.getX() - xOffset;  int y = (int)event.getY() - yOffset;`** `getX()` returns the X coordinate of this event for the first pointer index. So `getX()` gives the distance of the touched region from the left extreme side of the camera view, which includes the black border on the left. So `event.getX()-xOffset` or `int x` is the distance of the touched region from the left extreme side of the camera "frame" (which does NOT include the black border of the camera view). *Likewise for `int y`.*

**Then are the lines which I have no clue about.**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're asking about these lines:

```
touchedRect.x = (x>4) ? x-4 : 0;
touchedRect.y = (y>4) ? y-4 : 0;

touchedRect.width = (x+4 < cols) ? x + 4 - touchedRect.x : cols - touchedRect.x;
touchedRect.height = (y+4 < rows) ? y + 4 - touchedRect.y : rows - touchedRect.y;
```

From what I can tell, it's basically just making sure that Rectangle height and width don't wander out of frame.

Breakdown of why -

The `?` operator (called the ternary operator) in Java is basically a shorthand of if/else - the line `touchedRect.x = (x>4) ? x-4 : 0` means

```
if (x>4) {
    touchedRect.x = x-4;
} else {
    touchedRect.x = 0;
}
```

So, for line 129, if `x > 4`, set `touchedRect.x` to `x-4`, else `0`.

line 130, if `y > 4`, set `touchedRect.y` to `y-4`, else `0`.

line 131, `touchedRect.width` becomes `x+4 - touchedRect.x` if `x+4 < cols`, else `touchedRect.width` becomes `cols - touchedRect.x`

line 132, `touchedRect.height` becomes `y+4-touchedRect.y` if `y+4 < rows`, else it becomes `rows - touchedRect.y`